# Javascript Promise calling a Promise confusion

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using Javascript/Typescript to create a `Promise` that returns and `PersonModel` object that is formatted. However I am getting build errors:

**PersonService.ts**

```
private encryptPerson(person: PersonModel): Promise<PersonModel> {
    return new Promise<PersonModel>(resolve => {  // <== line 332
        let password: string = person.password;
        this.encrypt(password).then((ciphertext: string) => {
            person.password = ciphertext;
            resolve(person);
        });
    },
        error => {
            console.error(error)
        });
}

private encrypt(value: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>(resolve => {
        this.encrypter.encrypt(value).then((result) => {
            resolve(result);
        },
            error => {
                console.error(error)
            });
    });
}
```

**Error**

> ```
> ERROR in ./app/pages/service/personService.ts
> (332,16): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
> ```

Any help of how I should structure this appreciated.

**UPDATE**

After advise from T.J. Crowder below, I have got the following:

```
private encryptPerson(person: PersonModel): Promise<PersonModel> {
    return new Promise<PersonModel>(resolve => {
        let password: string = person.password;
        this.encrypt(password).then((ciphertext: string) => {
            person.password = ciphertext;
            resolve(person);
        });
    });
}

private encrypt(value: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>(resolve => {
        this.encrypter.encrypt(value).then((result: string) => {
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You are messing with parameters passed to call target. Specify line that this error occurred on

Comment: @Justinas: It's a bit hidden, but they've indicated which line is line 332 in a code comment.

Comment: @Justina, please see the following:  `// <== line 332`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `Promise` constructor with *two* arguments:

```
private encryptPerson(person: PersonModel): Promise<PersonModel> {
    return new Promise<PersonModel>(resolve => { // <== line 332
            let password: string = person.password;
            this.encrypt(password).then((ciphertext: string) => {
                person.password = ciphertext;
                resolve(person);
            });
        },
        error => {                  // ** This is the
            console.error(error)    // ** second argument
        });                         // ** to the constructor
}
```

It only takes one argument. I suspect that second arrow function was meant to be attached to the `then` inside the first one.

Separately, if I'm correct about where you meant that second function to go, beware that it converts a rejection into a resolution using `undefined` as the resolution value. Since `undefined` isn't a `PersonModel`, I'm guessing that's going to be a problem as well.